#  Positioning Issue in Website

Tags: html, css

My webpage can be found at [http://www.sarahjanetrading.com/js/j/index.html][1]. All the images and XHTML+CSS is accessible by anyone.

I am a web designer with some knowledge of HTML and CSS. The webpage is having some positioning problems. I have been trying for a while now to fix the issues but in vain.

I would really appreciate any help from you guys.

Thanks

**EDIT** *After validating my HTML and fixing a couple of errors, the webpage has the following issue that need fixes: *

1) The uFlip image creating a blank space between the featured and the main content.

Comment: Design link gives a 404 error.

Comment: sorry about that. Fixed!

Comment: Missing images are simply from bad links. Maybe you have a relative path when you meant to have an absolute path. Maybe there's a typo (some browsers forgive upper/lowercase errors, some don't). Maybe you have extension .jpg when you mean .png. Maybe you forgot to upload the file! No matter what, it's always just a bad path or the image not being where you expect it to be.

Comment: You are pointing your images to this folder: http://www.sarahjanetrading.com/images/ is that correct?

Comment: actually, i have checked the image paths and the images & they are alright. They also DO show up on my own computer. I am guessing its a positioning issue, since some of my layout has also changed when i uploaded it on the server.(I had layout issues on my own computer also).

Comment: can't say anything without knowing the proper html and css.

Comment: @Jrod, not really. Because if i had done that, the other images(not just background images) would have also not shown up. So again, I think it is a positioning issue.

Comment: @punit why cant you see the html and css? its right there, just click on view source. And, its only about 120 lines of HTML and 270 lines of CSS code.

Comment: Where is the image file stored on the server?

Comment: Broken links are not caused by positioning.  You have bad URL's.   See my answer.

Comment: Thanks. Fixed the broken links. Images works fine. Still has positioning problems though.

Comment: I think your _"fix my website"_ question is way too broad and has too many components.  Each could be a whole separate thread focusing on a very specific issue by itself.

Comment: @Sparky672 Updated the question to focus on the two issues it currently has :)

Comment: Please expand the verbal description of your item #2.  _"Not fitting in the space"_ is very vague when the tabs look fine here in Safari.

Comment: I posted an update to my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to design it from the beginning. 
Use container as a parent div. Use a header div, a body or content div and a footer. Give your container a width but no height, instead give it a overflow:hidden. By doing that you managed to keep everything in order.

You can try to cut your designs header div from the end of the ipad image(that will fasten things up). Float ipad image left and others right.

In content section, jquery will make things easier. Don't forget to give a position:relative to content div and position:absolute to arrow divs.

Footer is also simple, float navigation left, and social buttons right.

Also don't forget to cut your psd correctly. Cut you uFlip as a png24 and cut it all, don't use borders as you did. there is no need doing that.

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 1):

**Your URL has got to be wrong.**

When I right-click on the broken image link [on your site](http://www.sarahjanetrading.com/js/j/index.html), I get this...

http://www.sarahjanetrading.com/js/j/images/uflip.png

Loaded in a browser, it gives this...

> **Not Found**
>
> The requested URL **/js/j/images/uflip.png** was not found on this server.

---

The image is actually loading fine at this other url...

http://www.sarahjanetrading.com/js/j/images/uFlip.png

See the minor difference in the two URL's?

**File-names are case-sensitive here.**

*uflip.png* versus *uFlip.png*

---

**Edit Regarding your Tabs Issue:**

Your container is 780 pixels wide.

Your tabs are constructed with a left/right padding of 140 pixels total as well as a 1 pixel margin between them.  The problem is that you do not know the actual width of the text within each tab.  Even if you did, it would be slightly different in each browser.

I recommend that you specify an exact width (258 or 259 px ?) and remove the left/right padding. It's how you constructed your orange tabs up top.

Adjust width accordingly...

```
#main-tabs li a {
float: left;
display: block;
text-align: center;
width: 259px;
color: #555555;
font-size: 18px; 
padding-top: 15px; padding-bottom: 17px;
text-shadow: 2px 0px 0px #ffffff;
filter: dropshadow(color=#ffffff, offx=2, offy=0); 
background: #e0e9ef; 
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #e0e9ef 0%,#d0d9df 40%,#b1bbc0 80%,#9ca6ab 100%); 
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #e0e9ef 0%,#d0d9df 40%,#b1bbc0 80%,#9ca6ab 100%); 
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #e0e9ef 0%,#d0d9df 40%,#b1bbc0 80%,#9ca6ab 100%); 
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #e0e9ef 0%,#d0d9df 40%,#b1bbc0 80%,#9ca6ab 100%); 
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffaf39', endColorstr='#e0e9ef',GradientType=0 ); 
background: linear-gradient(top, #e0e9ef 0%,#d0d9df 40%,#b1bbc0 80%,#9ca6ab 100%);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your images and fonts don't work because the URLs are incorrect. When I open the Chrome Developer console, I get:

> GET http://www.sarahjanetrading.com/js/j/images/uflip.png 404 (Not Found)
>   GET http://www.sarahjanetrading.com/js/j/fonts/Helveticaneuelt-roman-webfont.woff 404 (Not Found)
>   GET http://www.sarahjanetrading.com/js/j/fonts/Helveticaneuelt-roman-webfont.ttf 404 (Not Found)
>   GET http://www.sarahjanetrading.com/js/j/fonts/Helveticaneuelt-roman-webfont.svg 404 (Not Found)

It's a case sensitivity problem. Change:

`fonts/Helveticaneuelt-roman-webfont.woff` -> `fonts/helveticaneuelt-roman-webfont.woff`
`fonts/Helveticaneuelt-roman-webfont.ttf` -> `fonts/helveticaneuelt-roman-webfont.ttf`
`fonts/Helveticaneuelt-roman-webfont.svg` -> `fonts/helveticaneuelt-roman-webfont.svg`

`images/uflip.png` -> `images/uFlip.png`